# How to calculate average rating of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

There is an array data given below:

```
    const ratingData = [
        {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:5},
        {name: 'St. Zaviers School', rating:4},
        {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:3},
        {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:2},
        {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:3},
        {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:1},
        {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:4},
        {name: 'Mother Marys High School', rating:5}
    ];
```

In this array, I want to calculate an average rating of each School Data. But the problem is duplicate entries like there are 2 entries for "St. Mary's School" with different ratings. How can I combine into one and calculate its average Rating? I tried using the `map` function but for each entry but it's not working.

It's o/p should look something like this.
(It is just an example)

```
const output = [
     { name: 'St. Marys School', averageRating: 4},
     { name: 'St. Zaviers School', averageRating: 4},
     { name: 'Rahul English Medium School', averageRating: 1.5},
     { name: 'St. Francis High School', averageRating: 3.5},
     { name: 'Mother Marys High School', averageRating: 5}
];
```

Comment: `array.reduce()` is your friend here.

Comment: I would do this in multiple steps - first build a map of `name => ratings`, then average the ratings, then re-structure it into your desired output array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ratingData = [
    {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:5},
    {name: 'St. Zaviers School', rating:4},
    {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:3},
    {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:2},
    {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:3},
    {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:1},
    {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:4},
    {name: 'Mother Marys High School', rating:5}
];

let sumData = {};

for (let element of ratingData) {
    if (sumData[element.name]) {
        sumData[element.name].sum = sumData[element.name].sum + element.rating;
        sumData[element.name].n++;
    } else {
        sumData[element.name] = {
            sum: element.rating,
            n: 1
        };
    }
}

console.log('sumData: ' + JSON.stringify(sumData));

let averageData = [];

for (let element of Object.keys(sumData)) {
    averageData.push({
        name: element,
        rating: sumData[element].sum / sumData[element].n
    });
}

console.log('averageData: ' + JSON.stringify(averageData));
```

sumData is gonna be equal to

```
{
    "St. Marys School": {
        "sum": 8,
        "n": 2
    },
    "St. Zaviers School": {
        "sum": 4,
        "n": 1
    },
    "Rahul English Medium School": {
        "sum": 3,
        "n": 2
    },
    "St. Francis High School": {
        "sum": 7,
        "n": 2
    },
    "Mother Marys High School": {
        "sum": 5,
        "n": 1
    }
}
```

and average data is gonna be equal to

```
[
    {
        "name": "St. Marys School",
        "rating": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "St. Zaviers School",
        "rating": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "Rahul English Medium School",
        "rating": 1.5
    },
    {
        "name": "St. Francis High School",
        "rating": 3.5
    },
    {
        "name": "Mother Marys High School",
        "rating": 5
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `reduce()` in combination with a `Map` to detect duplicate entries.

First it reduces the original array to a `Map` that accumulates the ratings of duplicate entries in an array.

```
{
{'St. Marys School': [5, 3, 1]},
{'St. Zaviers School': [4]},
...
}
```

We then convert this `Map` back to an array using `Array.from` and reducing the array of ratings to an average.

```js
const ratingData = [
    {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:5},
    {name: 'St. Zaviers School', rating:4},
    {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:3},
    {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:2},
    {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:3},
    {name: 'Rahul English Medium School', rating:1},
    {name: 'St. Francis High School', rating:4},
    {name: 'Mother Marys High School', rating:5},
    {name: 'St. Marys School', rating:1}
    ]
    
const mapData = ratingData.reduce((acc, {name, rating}) => {
  const match = acc.get(name);
  match ? 
  match.push(rating) :
  acc.set(name, [rating]);
  return acc;
}, new Map);

const averageArray = Array.from(mapData, ([name, ratings]) => {
  const rating = ratings.reduce((a, r) => (a + r))/ratings.length;
  return { name, rating }
});

console.log(averageArray);
```

Comment: Your "averaging" is flawed. `5, 3, 1` should average to `3` but your code averages it to `2.5` since it first averages `5,3 => 4` and then `4,1 => 2.5`